# Aspnet core cookie [Authorize] not redirecting on ajax calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, cookies

In an asp.net core 3.1 web app with cookie-based authorization I have created a custom validator which executes on the cookie authorization's OnValidatePrincipal event. The validator does a few things, one of those is check in the backend if the user has been blocked. If the user has been blocked, The `CookieValidatePrincipalContext.RejectPrincipal()` method is executed and the user is signed out using the `CookieValidatePrincipalContext.HttpContext.SignOutAsyn(...)` method, as per the MS docs.

Here is the relevant code for the validator:

```
    public static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext cookieValidatePrincipalContext)
    {
        var userPrincipal = cookieValidatePrincipalContext.Principal;

        var userService = cookieValidatePrincipalContext.GetUserService();

        var databaseUser = await userService.GetUserBySidAsync(userPrincipal.GetSidAsByteArray());

        if (IsUserInvalidOrBlocked(databaseUser))
        {
            await RejectUser(cookieValidatePrincipalContext);

            return;
        }
        else if (IsUserPrincipalOutdated(userPrincipal, databaseUser))
        {
            var updatedUserPrincipal = await CreateUpdatedUserPrincipal(userPrincipal, userService);

            cookieValidatePrincipalContext.ReplacePrincipal(updatedUserPrincipal);
            cookieValidatePrincipalContext.ShouldRenew = true;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsUserInvalidOrBlocked(User user)
        => user is null || user.IsBlocked;

    private static async Task RejectUser(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        context.RejectPrincipal();

        await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

And here is the setup for the cookie-based authorization:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(co =>
            {
                co.LoginPath = @$"/{ControllerHelpers.GetControllerName<AuthenticationController>()}/{nameof(AuthenticationController.Login)}";
                co.LogoutPath = @$"/{ControllerHelpers.GetControllerName<AuthenticationController>()}/{nameof(AuthenticationController.Logout)}";
                co.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                co.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                co.Cookie.Name = "GioBQADashboard";

                co.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = UserPrincipalValidator.ValidateAsync
                };

                co.Validate();
            });
```

This actually gets called and executed as expected and redirects the user to the login page when they navigate to a new page after having been blocked.

Most of the views have ajax calls to api methods that execute on a timer every 10 seconds. For those calls the credentials also get validated and the user gets signed out. However, after the user has been signed out, a popup asking for user credentials appears on the page:

[image]

If the user doesn't enter their credentials and navigate to another page, they get taken to the login page as expected.
If they do enter their credentials, they stay logged in, but their identity appears to be their windows identity...
What is going on here? What I would really want to achieve is for users to be taken to the login page for any request made after they have been signed out.

I have obviously misconfigured something, so that the cookie-based authorization doesn't work properly for ajax requests, but I cannot figure out what it is.
Or is it the Authorization attribute which does not work the way I'm expecting it to?

Answer (score 2):

The code lines look good to me.

This login dialog seems to be the default one for Windows Authentication. Usually, it comes from the **iisSettings** within the **launchSettings.json** file. Within Visual Studio you'll find  find the latter within your Project > Properties > launchSettings.json

There set the windowsAuthentication to false.

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
   }
}
```

Comment: That solved the issue, thank you! It looks like in absence of a cookie the authetication reverted back to windows authentication.